# $\sum_{j=2}^{n}\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}kj=\frac{1}{24}(x-1)x(x+1)(3x+2)$

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, number-theory, polynomials, stirling-numbers

How can I get from $\sum_{j=2}^{n}(\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}kj)$ the equation $\frac{1}{24}(x-1)x(x+1)(3x+2)$

Who would  the equation be the following case?

$\sum_{j=3}^{n}(\sum_{m=2}^{j-1}(\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}kmj))=?$

Comment: These are just the elementary symmetric polynomials over the first n natural numbers, e_2 and e_3. For e_k, they are given in general by [n+1,n-k+1], where the brackets denote the Stirling numbers of the first kind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the [Hockey-Stick identity](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Combinatorial_identity):
$$\sum_{j=2}^{n}j\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}k = \sum_{j=2}^{n}j\binom{j}{2}=3\sum_{j=2}^{n}\binom{j}{3}+2\sum_{j=2}^{n}\binom{j}{2}=3\binom{n+1}{4}+2\binom{n+1}{3} $$
and the RHS of the last identity can also be written as $\frac{3n+2}{4}\binom{n+1}{3}$.

In a similar way,
$$ \begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{j=3}^{n}\sum_{m=2}^{j-1}\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}kmj = \sum_{j=3}^{n}\sum_{m=2}^{j-1}jm\binom{m}{2}&=&3\sum_{j=3}^{n}\sum_{m=2}^{j-1}j\binom{m}{3}+2\sum_{j=3}^n\sum_{m=2}^{j-1}j\binom{m}{2}\\&=&3\sum_{j=3}^{n}j\binom{j}{4}+2\sum_{j=3}^{n}j\binom{j}{3}\\&=&\sum_{j=3}^{n}\left[15\binom{j}{5}+12\binom{j}{4}+8\binom{j}{4}+6\binom{j}{3}\right]\\&=&15\binom{n+1}{6}+20\binom{n+1}{5}+6\binom{n+1}{4}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

As suggested in the comments, shortcuts are given by [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind), since we are dealing with the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jack D'Aurizio
I find it very interesting!
Where can I find more information, can you recommend me a book oder Links?
Thank you!